# How to divide multiline text by types? Python

Tags: python, regex, split, multiline

I have a text written in a multiline

```py
text = '''Monday
1-t type1
2-d type2
Tuesday
1-t type1
2-d type2
3-rd type3
4-th type4
Wednesday
1-t type1
Thursday
1-t type1
2-d type2
3-rd type3
4-th type4
Friday
2-d type2
3-rd type3
4-th type4
Saturday
2-d type2
3-rd type3
Sunday
1-t type1
2-d type2'''
```

I need to sort the text by day.

```py
monday = [types..]
Tuesday = [types..]
```

what ways are there for this?

how to write the received data to 1 array?

Answer (score 2):

There is many ways of doing it, e.g. by defining a set of `headers` on which you can match the line, and if it's matching you can update the current header to write the next lines to.

```
from collections import defaultdict

headers = {'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday', 'Saturday', 'Sunday'}
lists = defaultdict(list)
header = 'Monday'
for line in text.splitlines():
    if line in headers:
        header = line
    else:
        lists[header].append(line)

print(lists)
```